# Generating stronger ObjectID values

Tags: mongodb

By default, MongoDB will attach a random 3-byte counter to the epoch-machine-process segment of a generated ObjectID. Is there any way I can configure MongoDB to increase this random sequence? For example, what if I would want it to generate an 8-byte sequence instead?

I understand that this can be done in code, but I was wondering if it is possible right at the configuration level.